# Trouble setting connection string

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form all set up and I am trying to return a record set.  I've tried this a million ways and get various err msgs.  What I can see happening is that my connection string just isn't going through.  I've checked my spelling and verfied sp is in the database.

```
   Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
   Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
   Dim strSQL As String
   Dim strOutput As String

   strSQL = " exec my sp"
   cnn.connectionstring = "my connectionstring which is good"
   cnn.open

   rs.open strSQL, cnn

   Do Until rs.EOF  'error here, Operation is not allowd when object is closed
        strOutput = strOutput + rs.Fields(1)
        rs.MoveNext
   Loop

   MsgBox strOutput
```

Kinda stuck right there and I'm already bald so I can't pull my hair out anymore.  Please for some kind guidance.

EDIT: I've added `SET NOCOUNT ON` to my sp and it appears the rs opens but now my error is on the next line, "item cannot be found in the collection correspong to the requested name or ordinal"

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test the last part of your code put for setting and opening the connection try to change your code as shown below:

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strOutput As String

strSQL = " exec my sp"
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.Open "Your connection string"
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenStatic
```

Comment: Thanks but same err in same place

Comment: What does your SP actually do?

Comment: It's returns an output parameter.  I needed to change `strOutput = strOutput + rs.Fields(1)` to `strOutput = strOutput + rs.Fields(0)`.  It had been a long week.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. Just one observation, since you only return a single value as output you could remove the `Do Until` loop.

Comment: ha! Actually at the end of that work day I figured out that I could remove that loop after talking outloud with my boss how it was working.:-)

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else coming across this my issue was actually really simple.  The recordset was set to return one value from and output parameters in the sp.  Recordset fields start at 0, not 1, hence my error.

```
strOutput = strOutput + rs.Fields(0)
```

That's all I needed to do.